# Стили для SVG Object

Tags: jquery, svg, объекты

Подключаем SVG через Object:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/krug-2.svg" width="auto" height="28" class="object-class" id="object-id">
Браузер не поддерживает SVG
</object>
```

Код SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="svg-id" class="svg-class" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 29 29" style="enable-background:new 0 0 29 29;" xml:space="preserve">
<g><path class="st0" d="M14.5,29C6.5,29,0,22.5,0,14.5C0,6.5,6.5,0,14.5,0C22.5,0,29,6.5,29,14.5C29,22.5,22.5,29,14.5,29z M14.5,1
        C7,1,1,7,1,14.5C1,21.9,7,28,14.5,28C21.9,28,28,21.9,28,14.5C28,7,21.9,1,14.5,1z"/></g>
</svg>
```

Стилизуем с помощью скрипта:

```
var object = document.getElementById("object-id"); //получаем элемент object
var svgDocument = object.contentDocument; //получаем svg элемент внутри object
var svgElement = svgDocument.getElementById("svg-id"); //получаем любой элемент внутри svg
svgElement.setAttribute("fill", "red"); //меняем атрибуты выбранного элемента
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Как получить объект по class? (getElementsByClassName не срабатывает)
2. Возможно ли добавить стиль для SVG объекта при hover на другой элемент (например, на его родитель)

Comment: Попробуйте `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: @Kosta B. не работает

Comment: вообще если svg подключенный по url то ни как

Comment: @Максим Ленский почему? Можно подробнее? Если по id скрипт его отлавливает и задает стили, почему не может это сделать по классу?

Comment: т.е вы говорите что если вы обращаетесь по ID то можете кастомизировать  SVG который подключен по URL, я верно понял ?

Comment: @Максим Ленский именно так. Попробуйте сами, посмотрите на живом примере. Заметьте, файл подключен не как img, а как object, что позволяет работать с ним через скрипт.

Скрипт находит объект по id, находит в нем svg по id, стилизует. Но сделать то же самое по классу не получается. Почему, понять не могу

Comment: я наверно чего то не понимаю .. простите за оффтоп

Comment: @Максим Ленский возможно) Но вы, может быть, хорошо знаете JQuery? Я сейчас этим похвастать не могу, поэтому не получается написать рабочий скрипт.

Если абстрагироваться от SVG - как выловить элемент по классу в теневом(полимерном) объекте?

Comment: @Amsterdam я в SVG я вот таким занимаюсь : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wjjNqV  люблю рисовать .... эту девочку я рисовал больше месяца ...но как таковой задачи добраться до svg dom из вне не было